# How to send notifications to set of users?

Tags: signalr

I am using SignalR for displaying onscreen notifications in my web application(built using Asp.net MVC).

My question is How to show notifications to specific set of users eg. Display onscreen notifications to all the users with reader role?. The roles and user associated with roles are defined the database.

I have read it in the documentation where it is mentioned about groups. But i am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, one of the ways to go is by using [SignalR Groups.](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups)

Basically, when you start the connection to the SignalR hub, you can also include that user in a group, based on the type of account (try not to include the user in a group based on a client function call, do it on the server).

So each time the user connects, you can override the `OnConnected` method and add a user on the appropriate group (in the `Groups` object are stored `ConnectionId` strings.

Note - if you are going to scale the application, you will also need to add a backplane for the following reason: the groups and the connection ids are store in the memory of the server. If your application is load balanced, then you have multiple independent instances of the same application, each one with different connections.

The way to go here is to use a [SignalR Backplane.](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr)

Hope this helps!

Best of luck!